# How to Install socket.io for .NET in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, macos, socket.io, monodevelop, nuget-package

I was wondering a library for socket.io in C#/.NET

I found one in : https://socketio4net.codeplex.com/

I am using MonoDevelop for Unity3D Mac OS X. In the above link I followed their instruction, I installed NuGET in Monodevelop too. But I can't install the socket.io for .NET using NuGET.

Can I actually do it using MonoDevelop in Mac? or I have to use different IDE or OS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDevelop for Unity 3D does not include a Package Console Manager out of the box. You can use the Manage Packages dialog instead.

The Manage Packages Dialog can be opened from the Projects menu by selecting Manage NuGet Packages. It can also be opened by selecting the Solution window, right clicking either the solution, the project or the project's references and selecting Manage NuGet Packages.

I see an `Unable to resolve dependency 'newtonsoft.json (>= 4.0.8)`. This is a NuGet case sensitivity problem. You can workaround this by installing Newtonsoft.Json before you install the SocketIO4Net.Client NuGet client.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually I didn't get any error. In Mac, from Monodevelop Menu  > Add-in manager, I installed NuGet. Now, to install SocketIO4NET.CLIENT I have to run a command i.e., Install-Package SocketIO4NET.CLIENT in Package Manager Console. But I couldnt find such things in Monodevelop

Comment: MonoDevelop for Unity 3D does not include a Package Console Manager out of the box. There is one available as a separate addin for Xamarin Studio and MonoDevelop 5.9 or later. You can use the Manage Packages dialog instead. The Manage Packages Dialog can be opened from the Projects menu by selecting Manage NuGet Packages. It can also be opened by selecting the Solution window, right clicking either the solution, the project or the project's references and selecting Manage NuGet Packages.

Comment: Hello, I have firstly added Newtonsoft.JSON (JSON.NET) and then tried to add SocketIO4NET.CLIENT. I got the following error : _Could not install package 'SocketIO4Net.Client 0.6.26'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not install package 'SocketIO4Net.Client 0.6.26'._

Comment: SocketIO4Net.Client 0.6.26 only supports projects that target .NET 4.0 or higher.

Comment: I got this :) I changed the target to .NET 4.0 in Assembly-CSharp > Options > Build > General.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, you may want to use the native Sockets to monodevelop environment. 
Check the libraries System.Net and System.Net.Sockets:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Net.Socket/

Also, see:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463947/Working-with-Sockets-in-Csharp/

Cheers and happy coding !